# OSError: out of pty devices with python sh

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running a pyinstaller binary in a chroot environment. The following code produces a traceback.

```
from sh import ps, grep
    grep(ps('-ef'), '[p]rovision_storage.py', _tty_in=True)

File "sh.py", line 1427, in call
File "sh.py", line 767, in init
File "sh.py", line 1780, in init
File "pty.py", line 29, in openpty
File "pty.py", line 70, in _open_terminal
OSError: out of pty devices
```

_tty_in set to False also produces the same traceback.

Environment: Pyinstaller binary compiled with Python 2.7.13
Compile/Runtime chroot OS: Debian Stretch

Answer (score 1):

Just mount `devpts` device into the chroot environment:

```
# mount --bind /dev /path/to/chroot/dev
# mount -t devpts none /path/to/chroot/dev/pts
```

Comment: Prefer --rbind over --bind